# How to use WebRTC for broadcasting to 100s recipients?

Tags: webrtc, broadcasting

Practical situation, we have a lecture/webinar and I want lecturer to broadcast online 1 way to 100 students at the same time, how would I do that with WebRTC?

I have tried Youtube Live Event today - their concept is similar to my needs and they seems to be using WebRTC as well, but there should be some re-broadcasting server to keep one connection from broadcaster and deliver it to many clients.

Comment: you can check out webrtc conferencing..many projects are already developed search on the web. A simple application server logic should do.

Comment: try checking out kurento media server's [one-to-many broadcast](https://www.kurento.org/docs/current/tutorials.html#tutorial-3-webrtc-one-to-many-broadcast)

Comment: Unless that lecturer has a seriously beefy machine with fantastic internet connection, you'll need some server infrastructure that can rebroadcast and distribute your WebRTC stream. Which turns this into a software recommendation question...

Comment: Lecturer don't have fantastic Internet connection thats why I am looking to keep one peer connection from lecturer and server re-broadcasting it to all connected students.